# Unable to retieve dynamic sObject field value

Tags: apex, sobject, dynamic, sobjecttype, sobjectfield

Trying to retrieve value of field from any given query on sobject. But when i have to traverse across multiple objects to fetch the value, I am not getting expected result.

Ex: to get value of owner.name in below query, I have to do

```
s.getSobject('Owner').get('Name');
```

I am able to build the above string properly but unable to fetch the value. Please look into my below code:

```
List<sObject> a = [select id, owner.name from case limit 1];
String[] so = new String[]{'id','owner.name'};
for(sObject s :a){
    for(String str : so) {
        string fieldvalue = str.replace(' ','');
        if (str.contains('.')){
            List<String> strList = new List<String>(str.split('\\.'));
            String temp = 's.';
            for(Integer i = 0; i < strList.size() -1; i++) {
                temp += 'getSobject('+strList[i]+').';
            } 
            temp += 'get(' + strList[strList.size()-1] + ')';
            fieldValue = (string) temp;    // getting correct string as expected but this not being evaluated to correct field value        
        } else {
            fieldvalue = (string) s.get(fieldvalue); //This is working fine
        }
        system.debug(fieldvalue);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure why you're manipulating the fields you're given... take a look at [FieldReference](https://github.com/bluewolf-beyond/selector/blob/master/src/classes/FieldReference.cls), it could save you a lot of work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were you, I would just copy the [FieldReference](https://github.com/bluewolf-beyond/selector/blob/master/src/classes/FieldReference.cls) class into your org and use it as follows:

```
Opportunity someRecord = [SELECT Account.Owner.Name FROM Opportunity LIMIT 1];
Object owner = FieldReference.build('Account.Owner.Name').getFrom(someRecord);
```

However, if you prefer to roll your own method, it should look something like:

```
public with sharing class CrossObject
{
    public static Object get(SObject record, String field)
    {
        if (record == null) return null;
        if (!field.contains('.')) return record.get(field);
        return get(
            record.getSObject(field.substringBefore('.')),
            field.substringAfter('.')
        );
    }
}
```

The first example would still work here, though you would have to change your signature slightly.

```
Object owner = CrossObject.get(someRecord, 'Account.Owner.Name');
```

Bonus in using `FieldReference` is that the unit tests are already written for you.

Answer (score 2):

Here the problem is that temp is a String and you try to assign one String into other. Remember `s.getSobject('Owner').get('name')` returns object and to convert into String user try to **typecast into String** that you did. So it is not possible to get the right answer until you use it as a String. Hope it clears you.
You can use the below code

```
List<sObject> a = [select owner.name, id from case limit 1];

String[] so = new String[]{'id','owner.name'};

for(sObject s :a)
{
    for(String str : so) {

        string fieldvalue = str.replace(' ','');

        if (str.contains('.')){

            List<String> strList = new List<String>(str.split('\\.'));

            String first = '';

            String second = '';

            for(Integer i = 0; i < strList.size() -1; i++) {

                first = strList[i];

            } 
            second = strList[strList.size()-1];
            //fieldValue = (string) obj;    // getting correct string as expected but this not being evaluated to correct field value        
            fieldValue = (String)s.getSObject(first).get(second);
        } else {
            fieldvalue = (string) s.get(fieldvalue); //This is working fine
        }
        system.debug(fieldvalue);
    }
}
```