# ERROR: Dynamic sorting in Wrapper class' column header

Tags: apex, visualforce, wrapper-class, sort, comparable

I have implemented a Wrapper class using this: [Salesforce Wrapper Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Wrapper_Class). Now I am trying to implement sorting for the column header which turns out to be throwing error:

> Invalid field Account.Name for Contact.
>   Error is in expression '{!sortWrpLst}' in page myVfWrapperPage: Class.myWrapper.cContact.compareTo: line **, Column 1
>   Class: Class.myWrapper.cContact. sortWrpLst: line **, Column 1
>
> An unexpected error has occurred. Your development organization has been notified.

Visualforce Page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Case" extensions="myWrapper" tabStyle="Create_New_Incident__tab">
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageMessages />
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!contacts}" var="c" id="table">
        <apex:column >
            <apex:facet name="header">
                <apex:inputCheckbox onclick="selectCheckboxes(this,'inputId')"/>
            </apex:facet>
            <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!c.selected}" id="inputId"/>
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column>
            <apex:facet name="header">
                <apex:commandLink value="Name {!IF(compareField=='Name',IF(sortOrder='asc','▼','▲'),'')}" action="{!sortWrpLst}">  
                    <apex:param name="compareField" value="Name" assignTo="{!compareField}" />  
                    <apex:param name="orderType" value="{!IF(sortOrder='asc', 'desc', 'asc')}" assignTo="{!sortOrder}" />  
                </apex:commandLink> 
            </apex:facet>
            <apex:outputField value="{!c.con.Name}"/>
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column>
            <apex:facet name="header">
                <apex:commandLink value="Hospital {!IF(compareField=='Account.Name',IF(sortOrder='asc','▼','▲'),'')}" action="{!sortWrpLst}">  
                    <apex:param name="compareField" value="Account.Name" assignTo="{!compareField}" />  
                    <apex:param name="orderType" value="{!IF(sortOrder='asc', 'desc', 'asc')}" assignTo="{!sortOrder}" />  
                </apex:commandLink> 
            </apex:facet>
            <apex:outputField value="{!c.con.Account.Name}"/>
        </apex:column>
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:form>
```

Class:

```
public class myWrapper{
public List<cContact> contactList {get; set;}
public static String compareField {get; set;} 
public static String sortOrder{get; set;}

public myWrapper(){
    getContacts();
}

public List<cContact> getContacts() {
    List<Contact> conList = [SELECT Id, Name, Email, Phone, Account.Name FROM Contact WHERE Checkbox__c = TRUE ];
    contactList = new List<cContact>();
    for(Contact c: conList) {
        contactList.add(new cContact(c, false));
    }
    return contactList;
}


public void sortWrpLst() {  
    contactList.sort();  
}

public class cContact implements Comparable {
    public Contact con {get; set;}
    public Boolean selected {get; set;}

    public cContact(Contact c, boolean selectedBox) {
        con = c;
        selected = selectedBox;
    }
    public Integer compareTo(Object vCase)  
    {  
        cContact caseToComp = (cContact)vCase;
        if((String)con.get(compareField) > (String)caseToComp.con.get(compareField)){  
            return sortOrder.equals('asc') ? 1 : 0;  
        }
        else {
            return sortOrder.equals('asc') ? 0 : 1; 
        }
    } 
}  
}
```

Referred: [Dynamic Sorting](http://lc169.blogspot.com/2013/08/dynamically-sorting-list-of-object-with.html)

Comment: Since you're not using pagination, probably better to do column sorting client side. There are many good Javascript libraries out there for this purpose which are already written and well tested.

Answer (score 2):

**You should just do this sorting client side.** [There are plenty of solutions to this problem already out there](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+table+sort&oq=javascript+table+sort). But the reason you're getting the error is you're basically trying to do:

```
String accountName = someContact.get('Account.Name');
```

If you want to support cross object fields, you need to take a different approach. If you implement a `CrossObject` class like I posted in [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/178401/2995), you could just do:

```
String accountName = CrossObject.get(someContact, 'Account.Name');
```

That said, your algorithm is not very efficient, or maybe not even correct. You should be returning `-1` *somewhere* as part of your `compareTo` implementation, to indicate when one record should go before the other. Return `1` when it should go after, and `0` when they are equivalent. All three return values should be used in just about any sane sorting algorithm.

Comment: Whoever down-voted care to explain why?

Comment: Hi Adrian, I couldn't able to use this `String accountName = CrossObject.get(someContact, 'Account.Name');` as I am dynamically applying different **compareField** values as the process of clicking on the column headers. Can you please narrow it down for me? Thanks.

Comment: Even column header: Name is clickable, but the values in the column are not getting sorted. What might be I am doing wrong?

Comment: Yeah man you would us compareField instead...or ***just use Javascript***.

Comment: I am getting an error by using this: `String accountName = con.AccountId.get(con, 'Account.Name');`. Also I have tried this: `String accountName = Account.get(con, 'Account.Name');`. Error: `Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void get(Contact, String) from the type Account`

Comment: That's not how Apex works. I wrote a specific class called `CrossObject` which has that syntax. Generic `SObject` functionality has only the methods described [in the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm). The idea is that you do `con.getSObject('Account')` to get the parent record then `parent.get('Name')` to get the parent field value. The `CrossObject` class I pointed you to does all that for you. But again, ***you should just use javascript here***.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70579/discussion-between-arnold-jr-and-adrian-larson).

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage JQuery datatable for this kind of functionality where sorting, pagination, searching in the list can be possible.

Here is my poc where list can handle 10000 records.

**Class**

```
public with sharing class SortWrapper 
{

    public List<ContactInfoWrapper> ContactsWrapper {get; set;}    
    //added for paginnation
    public List<List<ContactInfoWrapper>> listofContactsWrapper {get; set;}

    public SortWrapper()
    {
        ContactsWrapper = new List<ContactInfoWrapper>();
        listofContactsWrapper = new List<List<ContactInfoWrapper>>();
        getContacts();
    } 

    public void getContacts()   
    {
        for(Contact s:[SELECT Id, Name, Email, Phone, Account.Name FROM Contact])
        {            
            ContactsWrapper.add(new ContactInfoWrapper(s)); 
            if(ContactsWrapper.size() == 999)
            {
                listofContactsWrapper.add(ContactsWrapper);
                ContactsWrapper= new List<ContactInfoWrapper>();
            }                
        } 
        if(ContactsWrapper.size() != 0){
            listofContactsWrapper.add(ContactsWrapper);
        }   

    }

    //Wrapper class
    public class ContactInfoWrapper
    {
        public Contact sObj{get;set;}
        public Boolean checked {get;set;}
        public ContactInfoWrapper(Contact con)
        {
            sObj = con;  
            checked=false;  
        } 
    }
}
```

**Visualforce**

```
<apex:page id="SortPage" controller="SortWrapper"  showHeader="false">
    <!--added for pagination-->
       <head>
        <apex:includescript value="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" / >
        <apex:includescript value="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.4/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" />
        <apex:stylesheet value="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css" />
        <script>
            j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
            j$(document).ready( function () {
                var contactTable = j$('[id$="contacttable"]').DataTable({

                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
   <!---End of Pagination--->

    <apex:form id="myForm">

        <apex:sectionHeader title="Contact"/><br/>

        <apex:pageBlock>

            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Contact Records" collapsible="false" columns="1"/>
            <br></br>
            <body>                
                <table id="contacttable" class="display">       
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th style="width:10%;">Select</th>
                            <th style="width:25%;">Name</th>
                            <th style="width:30%;">Account Name</th>                                
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <apex:repeat value="{!listofContactsWrapper}" var="contactinfowrp" id="removeTableInd">
                              <apex:repeat value="{!contactinfowrp}" var="con">
                               <tr >
                                  <td><apex:inputCheckbox value="{!con.checked}"/></td>
                                  <td>{!con.sObj.Name}</td>
                                  <td>{!con.sObj.Account.Name}</td>
                              </tr>
                            </apex:repeat>
                        </apex:repeat>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </body>
        </apex:pageBlock>  
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Outcome**

[image: contact sort]

Comment: Can you please make me understand where(line number) exactly you have implemented the column header sorting?

Comment: it is done by the library itself, refer `j$(document).ready` function

Comment: Can you help me fixing the error within my code?