# Invalid field Account.PersonMobilePhone for Opportunity

Tags: apex

When I run the below code, it gives me this error:

> Invalid field Account.PersonMobilePhone for Opportunity.

Code:

```
Opportunity opplist  = [Select id,account.PersonMobilePhone from Opportunity limit 1]l 
opplist.get('Account.PersonMobilePhone');
```

Comment: See my answer on this post: [https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/178400/how-to-use-getsobject-to-retrieve-related-data-in-a-null-safe-manner/303010#303010](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/178400/how-to-use-getsobject-to-retrieve-related-data-in-a-null-safe-manner/303010#303010)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't just call `get` cross object. You have to cache each step of the way if you want to use the dynamic approach:

```
Opportunity record = [SELECT Account.Name FROM Opportunity LIMIT 1];
Account parent = (Account)record.getSObject('Account');

Object parentFieldValue;
if (parent != null)
    parentFieldValue = parent.get('Name');
```

You could easily write a utility for such functionality. I wrote one such and called it `CrossObject` in an  example [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/178400/2995).

Note that you can just use a static reference and it's much easier to work with. No need to check  each relationship along the path for null, and no need for a utility or multiple lines.

```
String accountName = record.Account.Name;
```